# is it possible to implement the observable pattern having threads as observers and if so is it a good idea?

Tags: java, multithreading, observable

Im developing a system in java that will retrieve from a database emails waiting to be sent and it will load them in a temporary buffer. Whenever emails are detected on buffers the idea is to use the observer/observable pattern to notify the smtp servers. the point is to have each server running on a different thread and all threads are observing the buffers. if anyone can help me understand how to implemented i would appreciate it. I 've already used the observer pattern before but never with multithreading.

hope someone can help me since I've been searching a lot on the internet but i couldnt find any answers

Comment: You have each server running in a different *thread* or a different *process/machine*?

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the idea of an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You create an executor service backed by one or several threads (a thread pool), and you submit tasks to this executor service. The tasks are stored in a queue, from which the thread(s) of the executor service takes the tasks it must execute. When the queue is empty, the thread(s) wait for a new task to appear in the queue.

You could have a `Map<SmtpServer, ExecutorService>`, and submit all the mails you have found in the database to the appropriate executor service. Use [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to create the appropriate implementation of ExecutorService.